# Tomcat hot swap classes - Is there a way to tell if hot swap would fail?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am developing a web application and the feature to hot swap classes provided in Intellij IDEA is very useful for me. But, hot swap doesn't always succeed and IDEA reports that hot swap failed.

By looking at the code change I have done, is there a way to identify that a hot swap attempt will fail or not? So I can directly start a new debugging session instead of trying to hot swap?

Comment: What is the reason provided for the failure?

Comment: I think it depends on the change I have done. Here is one of the error messages. `Hot Swap failed Tomcat: delete method not implemented; Tomcat: Operation not supported by VM`

Comment: I don't think that is linked to the code. I think it is linked to the state of the JVM at the time.

Comment: But if I do different changes at the same line, one change may hot swap while other may not

Comment: That doesn't mean the state of the VM hasn't changed also, but okay. I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: Have you had a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056628/hot-code-replace-failed-eclipse ?

Comment: Yes. But I am mot running any test case. Also I am compiling in debug mode.

Comment: My guess is if the computed serialVersionId of the class changes (even if it's not a `Serializable` class), then hot-swapping isn't going to work. More specifically, if you change the code within a method, you're okay. But if you change the definition of the class (add/subtract members or methods), then it will fall-over.